# Get average time of day in SQLite from datetimes

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, time, average

I have times in SQLite in the form of '2012-02-21 00:00:00.000000' and would like to average times of day together.  Dates don't matter--just times.  So, e.g., if the data is:

```
'2012-02-18 20:00:00.000000' 
'2012-02-19 21:00:00.000000' 
'2012-02-20 22:00:00.000000' 
'2012-02-21 23:00:00.000000'
```

The average of 20, 21, 22, an 23, should be 21.5, or 21:30 (or 9:30pm in the U.S.).

**Q1) Is there a best way to do this in a SELECT query in SQLite?**

But more difficult:  what if one or more of the datetimes crosses midnight?  They definitely will in my data set.  Example:

```
'2012-02-18 22:00:00.000000'
'2012-02-19 23:00:00.000000' 
'2012-02-21 01:00:00.000000'
```

Now the average seems like it should be (22 + 23 + 1)/3 = 15.33 or 15:20 (3:20pm).  But that would misrepresent the data, as these events are all happening at night, from 22:00 to 01:00 (10pm to 1am).  Really, the better approach would be to average them like (22 + 23 + *25*)/3 = 23.33 or 23:20 (11:20pm).
[image: average of times illustration]

**Q2) Is there anything I should do to my SELECT query to take this into account, or is this something I have to code in Python?**

Comment: You need to define your "average" better. Seems like sometimes you want the date to matter but sometimes you don't.

Comment: @muistooshort Can you explain what makes you say that?  Unless I am misunderstanding my needs (and perhaps I am), I don't want the date to ever matter.  In fact, these fields might as well not have the date portion, so they could be like "22:00:00", "23:00:00", and "01:00:00" and I'd like the average of those to come out to 23:20.

Comment: You give two possible values for the "average": 15:20 and 23:20. The first only looks at the time-of-day, the second uses knowledge of the date transition to avoid a mod-24 adjustment to the hour handling.

Comment: @muistooshort Well, what I'm after is only the 23:20.  The problem is, I will not have all data for every date (there will be gaps).  Because of that, if I use your original code, the date information will matter but in a way that will not give me (in this example) 23:20 if I have a gap of a few days between values.  I would rather have a mod-24 adjustment, just not sure how best to go about that in SQLITE or Python.  Does this make more sense?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you're just drawing bad conclusions from a limited sample? The outlier problem might go away if you look at the whole dataset.

Comment: as i noted in my answer - your explanation of the data can only be represented by **complex numbers**, not real numbers (i added an illustration using a circle to clarify this concept)

Answer (score 2):

what do you really want to compute?

- datetimes (or times within 1 day) are usually represented as real numbers
- **time coordinates on a 24-hour clock are complex numbers**, however
- average of real-number representations of the times will give you dubious results...

i don't know what you want to do with edge cases like [`1:00`, `13:00`], but let's consider following **example**: [`01:30`, `06:30`, `13:20`, `15:30`, `16:15`, `16:45`, `17:10`]
[image]

I suggest implementing this algorithm - in **Python**:

1. convert times to complex numbers - e.g. compute their coordinates on a circle of radius = 1
2. compute the average using vector addition
3. convert the result vector angle to minutes + compute the relevance of this result *(e.g. relevance of average of [`1:00`, `13:00`] should be 0 whatever the angle is computed because of rounding errors)*

```py
import math
def complex_average(minutes):
    # first convert the times from minutes (0:00 - 23:59) to radians
    # so we get list for quasi polar coordinates (1, radians)
    # (no point in rotating/flipping to get real polar coordinates)
    # 180° = 1/2 day = 24*60/2 minutes
    radians = [t*math.pi/(24*60/2) for t in minutes]
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for r in radians:
        # convert polar coordinates (1, r) to cartesian (x, y)
        # the vectors start at (0, 0) and end in (x, y)
        x, y = (math.cos(r), math.sin(r))
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)

    # result vector = vector addition
    sum_x, sum_y = (sum(ys), sum(xs))

    # convert result vector coordinates to radians, then to minutes
    # note the cumulative ROUNDING ERRORS, however
    result_radians = math.atan2(sum_x, sum_y)
    result_minutes = int(result_radians / math.pi * (24*60/2))
    if result_minutes < 0:
        result_minutes += 24*60

    # relevance = magnitude of the result vector / number of data points
    # (<0.0001 means that all vectors cancel each other, e.g. [1:00, 13:00]
    #  => result_minutes would be random due to rounding error)
    # FYI: standart_deviation = 6*60 - 6*60*relevance
    relevance = round(math.sqrt(sum_x**2 + sum_y**2) / len(minutes), 4)

    return result_minutes, relevance
```

And test it like this:

```py
# let's say the select returned a bunch of integers in minutes representing times
selected_times = [90, 390, 800, 930, 975, 1005, 1030]
# or create other test data:
#selected_times = [hour*60 for hour in [23,22,1]]

complex_avg_minutes, relevance = complex_average(selected_times)
print("complex_avg_minutes = {:02}:{:02}".format(complex_avg_minutes//60,
                                                 complex_avg_minutes%60),
      "(relevance = {}%)".format(int(round(relevance*100))))

simple_avg = int(sum(selected_times) / len(selected_times))
print("simple_avg = {:02}:{:02}".format(simple_avg//60,
                                        simple_avg%60))

hh_mm = ["{:02}:{:02}".format(t//60, t%60) for t in selected_times]
print("\ntimes = {}".format(hh_mm))
```

Output for my example:

```
complex_avg_minutes = 15:45 (relevance = 44%)
simple_avg = 12:25
```

Comment: or maybe 1-dimensional finite space would be better representation than complex numbers - becase only points on the circle represent time points, but the vector results are within the circle :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can average dates.

What I would do is get the average of the difference in hours between the row values and a fixed date then add that average to the fixed date. Using minutes may cause an overflow of int and require some type conversion

sort of...

```
select dateadd(hh,avg(datediff(hh,getdate(),myrow)),getdate()) 
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the average distance of the times from midnight?

How about this?

```
SELECT SUM(mins) / COUNT(*) from
( SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN strftime('%H', t) * 1 BETWEEN 0 AND 11 
    THEN (strftime('%H', t)) * 60 + strftime('%M', t)
    ELSE strftime('%H', t) * 60 + strftime('%M', t) - 24 * 60
    END mins
  FROM timestamps
);
```

So we calculate the minutes offset from midnight: after noon we get a negative value, before noon is positive. The first line averages them and gives us a result in minutes. Converting that back to a `hh:mm` time is left as an "exercise for the student" ;-)

Comment: what about average of (`11:00`, `12:00`, `13:00`)?? surelly 00:00 is not exactly the expected result ;))

Comment: @deathApril - As I specified, I guessed that the requirement is context-dependent and assumes that the times are clustered around midnight. If that's the case, this is a reasonable solution. If not, then as you point out, it's not very appropriate ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Site Rosetta Code has a [task](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Averages/Mean_angle) and code on this subject, and in researching that I came across this wikipedia [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics#Circular_and_higher_dimensional_distributions). Check out the talk/discussion pages too for discussions on applicability etc.